# Best Practice for posting collection in Web APi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have html page consisting of JqGrid. JqGrid is bind through JSon data. There are multiple rows in a grid. User can edit the values in Grid and when he is finally done with manipulation then data is going to post back at Server using Web Api.

Presently I am using the Post method with following signature :-

```
public void Put(JObject u)
{
 //here iteration is made on Jobject data and finally changes saved to DB
}
```

Please suggest if this fine with Web Api context or there is better way to update collection in Web Api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For a small project your approach is totally fine.
- For bigger projects I use jQuery with a WCF web service with like this:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
      [OperationContract]
      [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      MyAnswer DoWork(MyData data);
      // ...
```

But be warned: It took me hours and hours of debugging with Fiddler to get it work the way I want.